# Android studio -add json list to array list

Tags: java, android, json, firebase

I'm building an app with android studio and firebase, it is a quiz app and I'm taking the questions from firebase :

```
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
    for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                type =(String)singleSnapshot.child("type").getValue();
        type = (String) singleSnapshot.child("type").getValue();
                answer= (String) singleSnapshot.child("answer").getValue();
        answer = (String) singleSnapshot.child("answer").getValue();
                book=(String)singleSnapshot.child("book").getValue();
        book = (String) singleSnapshot.child("book").getValue();
                chapter=(String) singleSnapshot.child("chapter").getValue();
        chapter = (String) singleSnapshot.child("chapter").getValue();
                op1=(String)singleSnapshot.child("op1").getValue();
        op1 = (String) singleSnapshot.child("op1").getValue();
                op2=(String)singleSnapshot.child("op2").getValue();
        op2 = (String) singleSnapshot.child("op2").getValue();
                op3=(String)singleSnapshot.child("op3").getValue();
        op3 = (String) singleSnapshot.child("op3").getValue();
                op4=(String)singleSnapshot.child("op4").getValue();
        op4 = (String) singleSnapshot.child("op4").getValue();
                Question=(String)singleSnapshot.child("question").getValue();
        Question = (String) singleSnapshot.child("question").getValue();
                QID=singleSnapshot.getKey();

        QID = singleSnapshot.getKey();
```

QuestionOptions obj =new QuestionOptions(op2,op1,op4,op3);
            QuestionOptions obj = new QuestionOptions(op2, op1, op4, op3);
                            QuestionStructure question = new QuestionStructure(Question,answer,obj,book,chapter, type,QID );
            QuestionStructure question = new QuestionStructure(Question, answer, obj, book, chapter, type, QID);

QuestionsList.add(question);
            QuestionsList.add(question);

```
    }
```

}

How can I change the code so the app will add questions to the question list from a json file (also from firebase)

Answer (score 0):

You can use gson library,where YourClass contains exactly the same attributes as the json file(yes,you can use a List of questions or whatever collection you need as an attribute) and then just use the same logic:

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
var gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
return gson.fromJson(yoursJsonString, YourClass);
```